# Symfony2 : Form View - add another field on entity field type

Tags: symfony

I have the following code in my `buildForm` method of my `FormType`

```
$builder->add('privileges', 'entity', array(
                'label' => 'Privileges',
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => true,
                'class' => 'AcmeStoreBundle:AdminPrivilege',
                'property'=> 'description',
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($category)
                {
                            return $er->createQueryBuilder('p')
                                    ->where('p.categoryid = :categoryID')
                                    ->andWhere('p.parentid = -1')
                                    ->setParameter('categoryID', $category->getId())
                                    ->orderBy('p.position', 'ASC');
                }
            ));
```

Here if the `parentid` is greater than -1, then i'd like to show further form components after the checkbox where `parentid` is greater than -1 is created.

I've searched over Google and have been unable to find a way to do this, can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

Mat.
If I understand correctly, you can inject parentid and entity manager to form type construct from controller.
So you can run query before add field to builder, and use if-else. For example:

```
public function __construct($parentId, $em)
{
    $this->parentId = $parentId;
    $this->em = $em;
}

public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $choices = $this->em->getRepository()->callNeededMethod();

    if($this->parentId){
        $builder->add([someFieldParams]);
    }else{
        $builder->add([anoutherFieldParams]);
    }
}
```